# Взаимодействие с картой, календарем, таблицами google

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, google-docs, google-calendar

Изучаю Kotlin, но ничего толкового не нашёл на просторах интернета

Вопрос: Есть ли какая-то возможность взаимодействия нескольких пользователей на карту, календарь и гугл документы?

Например, пользователь 1 - поставил метку на карте, пользователь 2 - поставил метку на карте. В итоге все видят эти метки.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, нет, для карт нету, а так было бы прикольно вместе с друзьями турмаршруты составлять.

Календарь: ну, в самом приложении есть такая механика, но вот реализована ли она внутри API - наверное, нет, а изобретать альтернативный клиент - хорошая идея, только если будет какая-то автоматизация (по будильнику включить чайник, подвязанный к Google Home, каминчик отключить, когда все по работам/школам/садикам)

По поводу документов могу сказать только одно - парсинг данных, введенных юзером в докс в определенном формате

Да, кстати, знал про плагины для гугл ассистента? Они могут быть встроены в само приложение Android, какие-то апишки просто обязаны быть. Я же как-то отправляю смски голосом в мессенджерах, доставку заказываю, т. д. Пользователи, между прочим и не подозревают, что общаются с приложением, а ассистент тупо принимает/выводит данные. Вот тебе пару толковых идей для котлин-приложения. Сам я в котлине только начинаю вариться, но уже изучил возможности, предоставляемые гуглом

Comment: Я начал этим интересоваться в том плане, что хочу реализовать структуру данных без своих или покупных физических ресурсов - без сервера. Тобишь все данные юзеры сами налаживают, а приложение просто их посредник - агрегатор

Comment: @MaxDown Тогда тебе следует хранить базу данных локально у самого пользователя либо предложить бэкап на гугл диск/айклауд (второе предпочтительнее - и у юзера место не занимается, и в сервере отпадает необходимость, и OAuth через гугл/эппл можно будет попутно наладить, вот только в случае с эпплом придется поморочиться - наверняка у них там свои претензии в плане обеспечения безопасного доступа к БД)

Comment: Второй вариант как раз рассматриваю, без затрат для разработчика и юзера

Comment: @MaxDown вот только эппл засыпет айфоновцев туевой хучей уведомлений о том, что "не следует другим приложениям давать доступ к своему айклауду"